# KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS must include a listener for CONTROLLER

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

##### Edit:

For anyone reading this (question maintained below) here is some short summary which might resolve your issue:

- The Bitnami Kafka 3.4 image appears to have been updated recently to use Kraft instead of Zookeeper by default
- To revert back to Zookeeper, add this to your environment variables in `docker-compose.yml`: `KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=no`.
- See also: https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/kafka

Essentially my problem appears to have been something like this, although I have only just come to this realization:

- My server which hosted Kafka (via Docker) power cycled
- As part of the restart process to get the docker container running again, it pulled an updated image from Bitnami
- This updated image switched to Kraft by default
- This meant my compose file was now in broken state because of the image update and the new defaults which came with it

---

I had a working Kafka development environment. It died after a reboot, and now I can't get it working again.

I cleared my system, removing all Docker containers, and attempted to start again.

My `docker-compose.yml` which was obtianed from https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/ is shown below.

There are a couple of modifications here, such as the port, and the listener config.

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/containers/main/bitnami/kafka/docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.yml
```

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "2"

services:
  kafka:
    container_name: "kafka1"
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.4
    networks:
      - "kafka_network"
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://0.0.0.0:29092,INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092,INTERNAL://kafka1:9092
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes

volumes:
  kafka_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  kafka_network:
    name: "kafka_network"
```

The docker container does not start when started with `docker compose up -d`.

I found this line in the log file. (`/var/lib/docker/containers/3bd1.../3bd1...-json.log`)

```
...
WARN KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS must include a listener for CONTROLLER
...
```

What confuses me about that is that I have previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76079791/dockerized-kafka-how-is-kafka-cfg-listeners-and-kafka-cfg-advertised-listeners) on Stack Overflow:

- Are the strings passed to Kafka for the configuration of the "listeners" and "advertised listeners" arbitrary?

The answer to that previous question didn't provide any information about how Kafka interprets these strings, but it also didn't disagree that they are arbitrary.

I am now very confused. I tried to start Kafka, and it failed to start producing a warning suggesting that I need to have a particular string (in this case `"CONTROLLER"`) used as part of my environment variables. This is presumably for one, or both, of the Kafka Listeners properties.

In short - I do not know what I am doing. This might be a total red herring. Essentially, the new version of the Kafka docker configuration (`docker-compose.yml`) doesn't seem to be working anymore.

I notice that the new `docker-compose.yml` doesn't say **anything** about **zookeeper**. I don't fully understand why this is. I believe it is the case that zookeeper was intended to be depricated, or removed, as a requirement. Maybe that happened in the last couple of weeks?

Comment: This is an open issue if you search the bitnami pages github

Comment: Regarding the edit - This is mostly why using no tag, i.e. `:latest`, or a "non-specific" tag such as `3.4` vs the actual release `3.4.0-debian-11-r21` (or an image sha), is not recommended when running containers in a reproducible manner

Comment: This applies to version `3.2` also. i had essentially the same issue. local cluster for dev, was off for a while, it pulled a new image when i spun it up and defaulted to `KRAFT`.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Kafka tag `3.4` defaults to start Kafka in Kraft mode. Specifically, image tag `3.4.0-debian-11-r22` switched this (older versions still require Zookeeper), and this was released in the last month. This means it needs a Raft controller, and not Zookeeper (KIP-500 is a document that explains why Zookeeper is being removed). That controller needs to be a defined listener. Its name is **still** arbitrary (see [`control.plane.listener.name`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_control.plane.listener.name))

There's [an outgoing issue](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/16243) that the new mode doesn't work properly in that container because they decided to do special logic to parse the value, and somehow `CONTROLLER` became a required string, even though it isn't for Kafka itself.

If you had a working Compose file, then you could have kept it. Deleting your docker images doesn't mean you needed a fresh start for everything

Regarding persisting your data, refer https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/kafka#persisting-your-data

Comment: I've done some further work since yesterday and I have added `CONTROLLER`. However now the container doesn't start at all. Theres no error message in the logs either. Might ask a seperate question about this if I don't get any further.

Comment: There's differing information about whether Kafka+Kraft is ready to actually be used for development/production at the moment. Some sources say "yes it's ready to be used", some others say "no it's only useful for experimental dev". This issue seems to suggest it's still in some kind of alpha state. Do you have any opinion on this? All I am trying to achieve here is to get a working (Dockerized) Kafka instance which I can do some development work with reading and writing to a few topics. It's just a single instance. Not distributed. Can you make a recommendation about which route to take?

Comment: Kafka 3.3.1 released announced it as "production ready", after having several releases before that. I don't think Kafka core devs would have said so, without at least a handful of people trying it out, for real. I've personally not tried it, to recommend one or the other, but all I know is that the bitnami images appear to be broken now, without explicitly setting `KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=no`, and adding Zookeeper back. Using image tag `3.4.0-debian-11-r21` would revert back to previous behavior